# I have an error in my program and cannot find out the reason why it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
        #txt must be a nonempty string. 
        if len(txt)<=0 or not isinstance(txt,str):
               print("type error: findNextOpr")
               return "type error: findNextOpr"
#In this exercise +, -, *, / are all the 4 operators
#The function returns -1 if there is no operator in txt,
#otherwise returns the position of the leftmost operator

        op=['+','-','*','/']
        for i in range(len(txt)):
               if txt[i] in op:
                   return(i)
               else:
                   return(-1)#this is the else statement I keep getting the worng answer with

print(findNextOpr("1+2+3"))
```

The indentation is not perfect but I keep getting the value -1. I tried removing the else statement and then the program runs perfectly. But I need the -1 to be returned if there is not operator in txt.
What is the error in my program? 
I am a newbie to Python. So please spare the hate.

Comment: Your code seems to do exactly what it is supposed to do, it returns `1`, which is correct.

Comment: I get the same result as @ThierryLathuille, Are you using the correct python version?

Comment: Yup..python 3.6.something

Comment: This code returns 1 for me too, the correct answer.

Comment: I'll copy-paste the result I'm getting. Yes I am still getting -1

Comment: That's the right thing to do. When asking a question about debugging, please always include the **exact** code you're running, the complete output (or complete error traceback), and your expected output. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure in your code that all of your indentations are correct, Python unlike other languages relies heavily on that to know what to run, so if that is off in your program that could be the issue

Comment: Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
    >>> 
     RESTART: C:\Users\Sheshank\Documents\TEST.py 
    -1
    >>>

Comment: The above is my result and I do hope my indentations are right

Answer (score 2):

When I run this code I get the intended result, 1. My guess is that the else statement after the for loop is slid in, so is executed if the first symbol isn't an op.

```
def findNextOpr(txt):
        #txt must be a nonempty string.
        if len(txt)<=0 or not isinstance(txt,str):
                print("type error: findNextOpr")
                return "type error: findNextOpr"

        op=['+','-','*','/']
        for i in range(len(txt)):
                if txt[i] in op:
                        print(txt[i])
                        return(i)
        else:
                return(-1)#this is the else statement I keep getting the worng answer with

print(findNextOpr("1+2+3"))
```

Comment: @Shesps it's the same code, I just made the spaces/indents lined up.

Comment: I just changed my indentations in my question post and I hope the indentations are not wrong.

Comment: The cool thing with code is you can just try it! Hope that fixes it for you :)